# Joining 2 tables in PHP

Tags: php, sql

This might be a dumb and very simple question, but I'm stuck and I've tried multiple ways already. So I have this code:

```
$RefLinksRAW    = $GLOBALS['DATABASE']->query("
    SELECT u.id, u.username FROM ".USERS." as u 
    LEFT JOIN ".TURNAMENT." as s 
    ON s.id_owner = u.id;");
```

But I want to also SELECT columns from TURNAMENT that corresponds to s.id_owner, how do I do that?

Basically I want to make a table that shows contents from both of those tables.

This is the TURNAMENT table, I want to make sure that 'id' from USERS table is same as 'id_owner' and also select 'wons' column

[image]

Comment: Add your tables structure to the question.

Comment: Your `JOIN` looks correct, what's the problem?

Comment: try to dump the query and run it inside `phpmyadmin` and see if you get resultset empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add the columns you are after to the SELECT section. For example,

```
SELECT 
   u.id, 
   u.username,
   s.somecolumn,
   s.someothercolumn
FROM 
   users u 
LEFT JOIN 
   turnament s ON s.id_owner = u.id;
```

Replace `users` and `turnament` with your actual table names, and `somecolumn`/`someothercolumn` with the columns you are after.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't notice that I can use s. before I defined it.